# Grid Data bound to Stored Procedure getting called multiple times

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have an application that uses an aps:GridView.  The GridView is populated using a DataSource that calls a Stored Procedure.  The DataSource passes parameters to the Stored Procedure based on some text fields.  The page has been running slower than wanted, so I was doing some checking.

I ran SQL Profiler while loading the page, and saw the Stored Procedure was being called
twice.  I stepped through the code and found out that in the Page Load Complete event was where this was happening.  In this event, I set the value of a parameter for the Stored Procedure, then did a DataBind on the GridView to pick up the data.  As I was stepping through the code, I watched the SQL Profiler.  When I got to the step of setting the parameter, the Stored Procedure had not yet been called.  When I stepped through that and got to the DataBind command (before running that step), the SQL Profiler showed that the Stored Procedure had been called.  Then I did the DataBind and the StoredProcedure was called again.

My question is, how do I get the parameters set, and get the GridView data bound, and only call the StoredProcedure once?  If I comment out the DataBind step, the StoredProcedure never does get called (which seems really strange to me...).

Can you help me on this?  Thanks.

Comment: Can you post some code so we can see what you're doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen if you assign the datasource in the design and also do it in the code behind.

Comment: So the only way to supress the call of stored procedure with default values would be to unbound the grid and manual set the datasource of GridView in the code behind.